# Start Outlook 2016 (64 Bit) automatically minimised to Windows 10 (64 Bit) system tray - No active Explorer object found

Tags: vbscript, windows-10, system-tray, outlook-2016

I have an issue with an auto start of Outlook 2016 at boot/log on which is intended to start Outlook minimised to the Windows system tray, such that once invoked at Windows 10 launch mail will be collected by the mail account(s) (NB. All POP in this case.) whilst the program resides in the system tray remaining invisible until required by the user.

The .vbs script below does function as required but much of the time it introduces two unwelcome issues.

1. The Outlook icon in the System Tray displays a 'cog' overlay with the message "Another program is using Outlook. To disconnect programs and exit Outlook, click the Outlook icon and then click Exit Now".
2. Attempts to open Outlook from the 'Open Outlook' context menu (right click Outlook icon in the tray) item causes a dialogue box to appear reporting "No active explorer object found". Clicking the "OK" option in response launches Outlook (though issue 1 - cog overlay) remains.

Neither issue is present when Outlook is started normally from the desktop so it would appear that the .vbs script is in someway responsible. I have used this script successfully (see also below: https://superuser.com/questions/467809/start-outlook-automatically-in-tray) in the past both as a startup menu shortcut and a hkcu 'run' registry entry.

Can anyone suggest the cause or alternately a suitable code revision to achieve correct function?  In case it is significant, Windows 10 is 64 bit Pro and the version of Office (including Outlook) installed is also 64 bit.

This is the code invoked by the .vbs script:

OPTION EXPLICIT

```
OPTION EXPLICIT

CONST PATH_TO_OUTLOOK = """C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"""
CONST SHOW_MAXIMIZED = 3
CONST MINIMIZE = 1

DIM shell, outlook

SET shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Open Outlook
shell.Run PATH_TO_OUTLOOK, SHOW_MAXIMIZED, FALSE

ON ERROR RESUME NEXT

' Grab a handle to the Outlook Application and minimize 
SET outlook = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
WScript.Sleep(100)
outlook.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = SHOW_MAXIMIZED

' Loop on error to account for slow startup in which case the
' process and/or the main Outlook window is not available
WHILE Err.Number <> 0
Err.Clear
 WScript.Sleep(100)
 SET outlook = NOTHING
 SET outlook = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
outlook.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = MINIMIZE
WEND

ON ERROR GOTO 0

SET outlook = NOTHING
SET shell = NOTHING
```

Having spent a number of hours on this issue over the weekend I thought that I had resolved the issues and got everything functioning as intended.

Working from similar samples of code I compiled a new script (see below) which I applied both as a shortcut in the Startup folder and also as an entry into the 'run' branch of the HKCU registry.

Now for the issue! Testing the script on two separate Windows 10 Pro (both 64 Bit architecture) systems both with Outlook 2016 64 Bit installed as part of a 64 Bit Office suite I found that whereas on one system the script runs flawlessly on the other I receive the following runtime error:

Script: D:\Neil's Files\Neil's Filing Cabinet\Neil's Emails\Start Outlook Minimised to Tray\Start Outlook 2016 Minimised To Tray.vbs

Line:   11
Char:   5
Error:  ActiveX component can't create object: 'GetObject'
Code:   800A01AD
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

This has me perplexed as the script file and it's related shortcut are both physical copies of each other given that the revised script below contains no path references (as these are handled directly by the code in respect of Outlook.exe) which are identified by the placement of either the shortcut or as the data element of the registry string whichever format is used.

The Systems do have some differences however and for comparative purposes I will summarise those I feel to be relevant here:

System 1: (The problem system) is an X58 Asus P6T7, Intel i720 mature PC with many programs installed and specifically the Outlook 2016 has the same 12 addins installed but in addition has two related programs which launch at boot, the enterprise editions of 4team's Sync2 for Microsoft Outlook and Safe PST Backup. The boot times are quite lengthy (but acceptable) as is the Outlook Startup with it's various addins.

System 2: Is a current generation Asus X99-Deluxe, i7 5930 new build pc with little installed as yet save MS Office, Adobe CC and some utilities.

In the case of System 1, Outlook auto-starts as intended however during it's loading splash screen (whilst it is loading up the addins) the runtime error is displayed although Outlook continues to open fully but fails to minimise.....

This suggests to me that the faulting code is the section which activates the window however the above error message refers to "ActiveX component can't create object: 'GetObject'" which suggests instead an issue with the code line "Set OLObj = GetObject("","Outlook.Application")"??

Hopefully somebody can test the code on a similar setup and report back? Or alternately, give me a pointer as to what is going on and how I might resolve it. I would of course also welcome any suggested improvements to the code!

** Quick Update **  Now tested on HP Elitebook 8440P Laptop - Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit with Office 64 Bit + same 12 Outlook Addons  - Functions as intended.....

** Further Update ** Tested on a second HP Elitebook 8440P Laptop - Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit with Office 64 Bit + same 12 Outlook Addons - Above RunTime error experienced once again.......struggling to comprehend why these results are occurring??  Any thoughts anybody???

The code below is offered "as is" for the benefit of anyone else seeking the same Outlook auto start criteria. The testing with System 2 indicates that it works so I hope others enjoy similar success until the outstanding issues are sorted.

NB: To adjust the Outlook Launch Window Size (during its 10 second pause prior to automated minimising) to reflect personal preferences change the numeric value in the following line of code:

WshShell.Run "OUTLOOK.EXE" , 3, false

For a maximised window size change the value to 3       For a restored window size change the value to 2

```
OPTION EXPLICIT

Dim WshShell
Dim OLObj 
Set WshShell = WScript.  CreateObject ( "Wscript.Shell" ) 
'Open Outlook: Note that inspite of the launch options, it will open the program in a normal window.
'The file location path is not necessary as Windows 10 correctly identifies Outlook's location.
WshShell.Run "OUTLOOK.EXE" , 3, false 
'This will mimimise it to the system tray after a 10 second pause to allow for mail collection on Outlook launch.
WScript.Sleep (10000)
Set OLObj = GetObject("","Outlook.Application")
'Activates the window
OLObj.ActiveExplorer.Activate
'Sends the command to minimise
OLObj.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = 1
'Outlook does not immediately minimise to the system tray so that 'Send/Receive' can initiate mail collection.
```

Thanks to jrv from Microsoft's "The Scripting Guys" forum who kindly offered a revised (simplified) code which is below. I can report that as with the original code it works flawlessly on the same 2 systems as before, whilst faulting once more on the other two......very much perplexed!!

The Runtime Error:

Script: D:\Neil's Files\Neil's Filing Cabinet\Neil's Emails\Start Outlook Minimised to Tray\Start Outlook 2016 Minimised To Tray.vbs

Line:   3
Char:   5
Error:  ActiveX component can't create object: 'Outlook.Application'
Code:   800A01AD
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

The revised code:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject ( "Wscript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run "OUTLOOK.EXE" , 3, False
Set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
ol.ActiveExplorer.Activate
ol.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like file *.reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"Outlook"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c \"start \"\" /min \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE\"\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences]
"MinToTray"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Hi Ovichan,

Thanks ever so much for your very clean and simple solution....exactly what I was looking for :)

I note that the registry entries you have suggested come from both the HKLM and HKCU hives......just wondering whether

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences]
"MinToTray"=dword:00000001  

could equally be composed as

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences]
"MinToTray"=dword:00000001   

for a global effect for all users?  Or does this present an issue I haven't foreseen?

PC Pilot

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer that works well with Office 2013 on Windows 7, and I hope it works for you too.

Essentially, this solution bypasses the issue with trying to force Outlook to minimize after loading. Instead, it relies on using a shortcut that's already configured to load the program in a minimized state.

1. Copy a shortcut to Outlook into the directory containing your script.
2. Right click the shortcut and open Properties.
3. In the Shortcut tab, change the Run mode to Minimized. Press OK.

[image: Screenshot of shortcut properties]

Then, all you need to do in your VBScript file is to execute the shortcut like so:

```
Dim sh : Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.run "Outlook.lnk"
```

Note that because this solution uses a shortcut, you could potentially remove the VBScript part entirely by putting the shortcut into the All Users Startup folder.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I had already tried to accomplish the actions in a more simple way however for whatever reason, these 'normal' solutions to this issue do not work in all cases. Specifically with Outlook I understand that it behaves differently from other office programs as 'minimising' is only one part of the action here.

Comment: To clarify: On initial login, the Outlook icon remains visible on the Taskbar forcing one to restore the window and then minimize manually before Outlook will remove itself from the Taskbar to the Tray.
•Simply adding the suggested 'minimised' Outlook shortcut to the Startup folder and also selecting 'Hide When Minimized' from the context menu of the Outlook Tray Icon does not solve the issue.
•Using the /Min flag from a batch file or shortcut doesn't work either for Outlook :(  (see: https://superuser.com/questions/467809/start-outlook-automatically-in-tray/1238464#1238464)

Comment: Oh dear. That does sound like a tough challenge. Any particular reason why a regular minimized window isn't sufficient?

Comment: Apart from the desire not to be beaten.....lol  Seriously, it is so that the entire boot + Outlook launch work totally in the background without cluttering the taskbar (untidy....OCD?) yet collecting mail so that when the user opens it (from the tray) their work is immediately available. Like I said it works flawlessly on 2 systems but errors on the other 2...Aghhhh!  :(

Comment: Computer software + OCD = always a nightmare, and I can attest to that! Did you try disabling all Outlook addins?

Comment: Indeed! My OCD determines much of how I expect my software to perform and a grim determination to satisfy the requirement doesn't help! As to your other point yes I have tried that....interestingly the working systems have the very same addins and the second faulting system DOES NOT have either of the 4team apps which eliminates them from the mix :(  I have also been given a more simplified code (see edit above) which also work/fail on the same Systems........still perplexed!

Answer (score 0):

It's me again! I have an answer that should bypass any issues with VBScript by using third-party software, [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/). I don't know how you'll feel about that, but I tested it and it works over here. I use this at home and at work to manage multiple monitors and various other things. It may even help solve problems with other programs you use and render various VBS hacks redundant.

In your case, there is a feature called 'Triggers'. Note that while there is a free version of DF, you'll have to activate a 30 day trial for the Pro version to use Triggers, and after that, it's up to you to decide if it's worth your while.

Firstly, after installing DF, you'll want to open up its settings window (right-click desktop and go to DisplayFusion > Settings).

Go to the Triggers tab and click Add.

[image: Triggers tab]

Set up the trigger for when a window is created. Tell the trigger to activate only *once* per process ID so it won't also try to minimize subsequent windows, such as when composing a new email. Find the path to your outlook.exe. Then, add an action on the right-hand side to minimize the window.

[image: Add Trigger window]

Click OK twice and then see if it works by loading Outlook. For me, the splash screen appears as normal, then the main window is minimized as soon as it appears.

DF runs as a system service with admin privileges and has been tested with tonnes of software packages, so if this method also fails for you, it could indicate bigger issues with your system/Office configuration.

Comment: Don't have access to the systems just now to try DisplayFusion as suggested.....looks interesting though, even if it does add another program into the mix!  One query that you might be able to answer.....and was an issue with the other minimising techniques...does the minimised Outlook disappear from the taskbar to the tray (hide when minimised must be selected) collecting mail?  This did not happen with the other 'run minimised' solutions remaining on the taskbar...Thanks!

Comment: Yes, when I enabled 'Hide when minimized' and used this technique, it did indeed disappear from the taskbar.